How to Access Firefox Local Storage via Command Line
I'm working on automating tasks in Firefox using xdotools on Debian, and I need to access the local storage of a website from the command line without closing Firefox. I'm aware that I can access URLs visited and cookies stored using the command lz4jsoncat ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default-release/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4. However, it seems that local storage information is not available in this file.
I've also discovered a SQLite file in the directory /config/.mozilla/firefox/*.default-release/storage/default/<website>/ls, but it requires closing Firefox to make queries on this file, because database is locked.
Is there a way to access Firefox local storage via command line without closing it? I'm using the latest version of firefox-esr on Debian. My goal is to print a specific value from local storage to the terminal after executing an xdotools command.

Copy the file to another location (i.e. /tmp) and open the copy
sqlite3 /tmp/copied.sqlite

